# vb.net WMP shows vertical bars even if played in full screen or StretchToFit

Tags: vb.net, zooming, wmp

When I use WMP i have an option to "Zoom to fill" this fills the entire screen regardles of aspect ratio obviously with aspect ratios like 4:3 there will be some automatic cropping involved. However I cant seem to get it done using the WMP control in VB.net

```
If AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying Then
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = True
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.stretchToFit = True
    End If
```

Either one of the options shown above do zoom to fill but only as far as the aspect ratio will allow (it wont crop), meaning in the aspect ratio of 4:3 the video will play with a vertical black bar on either side, Something which if the same video is played in standalone WMP would not happen.

How do I make the image fill the entirety of the screen without any bars?

Okay I see the issue now I have mistaken the Movies & TV app for WMP.  Perhaps if I get the aspect ratio from the MP4 file and then use the height of my screen to calculate the  width and resize the WMP to be wider than the actual screen size litturaly pushing the two vertical bars off screen?

Answer (score 0):

In light of research VCL library's are just as easy to use and are more suited to my situation